# Parse a string expression

Tags: python, regex, parsing, expression, eval

I need to parse a string which contains an expression. The language is proprietary and I am not sure I know the complete syntax but essentially an example expression looks like this:

`"some_name+(some_other_name * 4 * different_name)+ 'h40028"`

There are various names i've illustrated as some_name etc above which I need to replace with there integer equivalent from a dictionary I have stored. There is no constraint on the length of the expression in terms of how many variables or numbers are referenced.

I then need to evaluate the resulting expression. The grammar allows for whitespace and the basic mathematical operators: `+-*`(possibly `/`)

I know practically nothing of lexxers and parsers and hence I am looking for the simplest approach to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace according to your dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'Mark': 2, 'Susan': 1, 'Billy': 3}
strings = 'Mark + (Susan * 4 * Billy)'

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    strings = strings.replace(k, str(v))

print eval(strings)
```

Comment: And this is the part where I kick myself! Nice and easy solution!

Comment: I didn't understand the h40028 but I'm sure you can handle it from here on out. Please mark as answer if you can.

Answer (score 0):

For parse an equation you can use [`compiler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/compiler.html) module , (for get ride of the using `eval`'s risk !!! ):

```
>>> import compiler
>>> eq="some_name+(some_other_name * 4 * different_name)+ h40028"
>>> ast= compiler.parse( eq )
>>> ast
Module(None, Stmt([Discard(Add((Add((Name('some_name'), Mul((Mul((Name('some_other_name'), Const(4))), Name('different_name'))))), Name('h40028'))))]))
```

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I think its just a const ! but seems

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Yeah, it's just a constant. It's verilog syntax for a constant where the ' starts the constant and the h is the hex radix and the rest is obviously hex. Another variant could be 'b0100 where b is the binary radix.

Comment: @KasraAD Thanks for the suggestion. Malik's solution will get me out of jail this time so I can postpone delving into parsers!

Comment: Kasra, you seem to know a lot more then me. Why do people generally discourage `eval` and `exec` because they were made for a purpose, you know?

Comment: @GregoryKuhn you're welcome , about parsing you have many choice like `compiler` or you can use regex and `operotr` module and ... ! you can search and find many ways;)

Comment: @MalikBrahimi well it's  because eval and exec can result in execution of arbitrary code which can, in addition to exposing a security threat, it can also result in unintended consequences. My application is completely proprietary operates in a constrained environment so I am not worried about these risks. In general I take the viewpoint that if I need to use eval or exec, there is probably a better way to do it. However eval in this case is a very nice solution

Comment: @MalikBrahimi  Gregory explained good . using functions like `eval` and `exec` usually doesn't been recommended when you have to get the input from an external device or user !thinks about a command like `sudo rm -rf` that remove the hard !!!!!!